# Iterative deepening search using my DFS

Tags: java, search, iterative-deepening

I have a DFS search and now I am trying to implement Iterative deepening search with this DFS but I really do not understand what should I do. I have tried many ways but finally I found It was wrong! Do you have any suggestion that what changes should I do?

```
public void dfs()
    {
        Stack s=new Stack();
        s.push(this.rootNode);
        rootNode.visited=true;
        printNode(rootNode);
        while(!s.isEmpty())
        {
            Node n=(Node)s.peek();
            Node child=getUnvisitedChildNode(n);
            if(child!=null)
            {
                child.visited=true;
                printNode(child);
                s.push(child);
            }
            else
            {
                s.pop();
            }
        }
        clearNodes();
    }
```

Comment: your dfs function is not searching anything, it's just traversing the whole graph.

Comment: yes thats right and also I want to have same iterative deepening search

Comment: There is no point in doing an ids if there is no goal to reach

Comment: why? in each level it runs DFS completely. A DFS for level 0,1,2,... separately.

Comment: @user2944170 What data structure are you traversing? A binary tree or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, let's try something.

You need to change your function to limit the depth of the search. To prevent the lower level nodes to be printed multiple times, I will only print the nodes at maximum depth.

This gives:

```
public void ids(int limit)
    {
        for (int n = 1; n <= limit; ++n)
        {
            dfs(n);
        }
    }

public void dfs(int limit)
    {
        Stack s=new Stack();
        s.push(this.rootNode);
        rootNode.visited=true;
        while(!s.isEmpty())
        {
            Node n=(Node)s.peek();

            if (stack.size() == limit)
            {
                printNode(n);
                s.pop();
            } else {
                Node child=getUnvisitedChildNode(n);
                if(child!=null)
                {
                    child.visited=true;
                    s.push(child);
                }
                else
                {
                    s.pop();
                }
            }
        }
        clearNodes();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very helpful! finally it works. your change is very small and tidy.tnx